# How to get current sound clip file name in Unity c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script that basically plays music from the list. I'm trying to get a name of the current song but in return I get the name + (UnityEngine.AudioClip)

Here's a code I use:

```
currentSong.text = audioSource.clip.ToString();
```

Is there a way to get rid of (UnityEngine.AudioClip)? Because right now I get:

> SongName (UnityEngine.AudioClip)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `ToString()` here is probably adding information. Perhaps `clip` has a name property?

Comment: @Ibrennan208 clip itself is a property for the name of current song being played. ToString() just streams the name. I'm just confused why UnityEngine.AudioClip is shown right after it.

Comment: Are you sure about that? `ToString()` is a method that exists for all objects. In this case if you are using it and seeing the object type after that, the `ToString` was probably overridden to print out the name as well as the object type. As it turned out, my comment was your answer.

Comment: My mistake. Still learning :) @Ibrennan208

Comment: No worries, here is some further reading if you are curious: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-6.0#overriding-the-objecttostring-method

Comment: Also, if you find yourself waiting around too long for answers in the future, the documentation can sometimes be of help. Here is the documentation for Unity Engine `AudioClip`: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioClip.html

They often have all class members and descriptions about all of them in the documentation. In this case `name` is shown in the **Inherited Members Properties** and links to a description of the `name` property and where it is inherited from: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-name.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Suggestions:**

I believe this returns you the name of clip...

```
audioSource.clip.name
```

Hope it works... Happy coding :)

Comment: Oh my god, I cannot believe I missed it, lol. Thanks, I appreciate it!

Comment: lol... you are always welcome <3